# How to deploy the  war file of module wise

Tags: java, ant

i want to deploy the war files developed by different developers on module wise.All are using the NetBeans IDE for the development,this IDE itself will generate a jar file.But all the modules are inter related.Now i want to link all this war's.How to integrate it in the deployment environment?Can i use ANT tool for this?Then how to use it?

Comment: Any more information would be helpful too, e.g. what deployment environment, are the wars linked or separate applications, is there are requirement for deployment order etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant won't help you particularly, though you can probably do this in Ant.  Your build file would need to

- unpack the WAR files,
- copy the relevant bits into a temporary tree,
- add in customized properties files and modified versions of the original files, and finally
- create new WAR file or files.

If the WAR files are built using Maven, you can use Maven WAR file overlays to either:

- apply customizations to WAR files, or
- merge multiple WARs into a single WAR.